# Anthology book: man tricked he was dead by falling off a balcony, apocalypse with black spot on the sun etc

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, horror, anthology-book

Male author(s). I read this book between 1996-2000 and was published in the USA some time within that decade. It was written in English and was an anthology book. I can recall 3 stories though I believe there were more.

One story was about a young man who is visited by different friends of his girlfriend as he is unable to walk. Some kind of fall and eventually they convince him that he is already dead. That he fell off his high rise balcony during a party and even take him to the window and he sees his body.

It turns out they have been drugging him but he turns the tables on them and drops each of his girlfriends co-conspirators and his girlfriend last. He finds out the body they were trying to convince him was his was just a dummy that he ends up sleeping with afterwards.

The second story was about a writer who meets an obsessed fan who is wanting him to write her script, a la Misery. She blackmails him through sex and he ends up finishing her idea since he admitted it was a clever idea. He ends up taking her out to some kind of desolate area under some pretence of finishing the novel but he kills her instead.

The third story I recall very little about but it has to do with a brother and sister left after some kind of apocalypse which was started by a black spot in the sun. Not sure what else in this one...

There were more than just those three stories I think but those I remember.